# Update a variable number of parameters in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, coalesce

Assume the following please:

I have a table that has ~50 columns.  I receive an import file that has information that needs to be updated in a variable number of these columns.  Is there a method via a stored procedure where I can only update the columns that need to be updated and the rest retain their current value unchanged.  Keep in mind I am not saying that the unaffected columns return to some default value but actually maintain the current value stored in them.

Thank you very much for any response on this.

Is COALESCE something that could be applied here as I have read in this thread: [Updating a Table through a stored procedure with variable parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778344/updating-a-table-through-a-stored-procedure-with-variable-parameters)

Or am I looking at a method more similar to what is being explained here:
[SQL Server stored procedure with optional parameters updates wrong columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058891/sql-server-stored-procedure-with-optional-parameters-updates-wrong-columns?rq=1)

For the record my sql skills are quite weak, I am just beginning to dive into this end of the pool

JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use COALESCE to do this. Basically if the parameter is passed in as NULL then it will use the original value. Below is a general pattern that you can adapt.

```
DECLARE @LastName NVARCHAR(50) = 'John'
DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL;
DECLARE @ID INT = 1;

UPDATE dbo.UpdateExample
SET LastName = COALESCE(@LastName, LastName), FirstName = COALESCE(@FirstName, FirstName), 
WHERE ID = @ID
```

Also, have a read of this article, titled: The Impact of Non-Updating Updates

http://web.archive.org/web/20180406220621/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx

Basically,
"SQL Server contains a number of optimisations to avoid unnecessary logging or page flushing when processing an UPDATE operation that will not result in any change to the persistent database."

Comment: Two questions
Question 1, wouldn't it be exec dbo.UpdateExample, and then the actual UPDATE is written?

Question 2, Declaring @FirstName = NULL; when the update occurs if FirstName already had data in it wouldn't it be overwritten with the NULL value?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean with Q1. The example I gave, you could adapt to a SP - the variable declarations, of course, would be your SP parameters. About Q2, the COALESCE operator will prevent this from happening - ie. if @FirstName had data, it would not be overwritten, the NULL would be skipped and the old value retained.

Comment: Thank you @g2server I'll give this a spin and see how it goes.  I will be accepting your answer on this for now, have a great day.